# Lenovo laptop suddenly slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, lenovo-laptop

I have a new Lenovo E580 laptop (bought January 2019) which suddenly started to run very slow. I have especially noticed it with build times in Visual Studio and loading times for a local website in IIS.

I have tried to reinstall Windows 10 Pro by formatting the entire computer but it’s still slow.

Laptop spec:

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- CPU: i7-8550U 2.00GHz
- 16 GB RAM
- 512 SSD

Software where I really notice the slowness:

- Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.3.9
- IIS to Windows 10

I have tried to setup an older laptop with the same software installed as the new laptop, to compare the loading times. The old laptop has a very similar spec. (i7-4700MQ 2.40GHz, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD). The load time for a local website on the new laptop is 78 seconds where on the old is 30 seconds. On the new laptop it used to be around 30 seconds as well.

It’s not just Visual Studio and IIS that is slow it’s the entire laptop. I thought it would be fixed by reinstalling Windows but there were no improvements. I suspect it’s a hardware issue, but I don’t get any errors, and everything looks fine.

Does anyone have suggestions to what I can try to pinpoint this issue or is it better to contact Lenovo support, as the new laptop is still under warranty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been experiencing the same issues myself lately. But I updated BIOS & firmware via Lenovo Vantage today and it sorted everything out. The CPU consumes as much power as it needs and VS compilation process is pretty fast again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known bug of current Lenovo laptops (A list of models that have been reported to be affected can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MsqSYt0f_vU72pGGTWueeEgTBzd-HIz4ODHLmNOv16o/edit?usp=sharing)) that *might* be fixed by upcoming firmware releases. The laptop is unable to determine if you are using it on lap or on desk and thus falls back to lap mode, which results in throttling the CPU:

[image: PDF extract]

You can find more information in the PDF released by Lenovo here: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/X1C6-T480s-low-cTDP-and-trip-temperature-in-Linux/m-p/4534535/highlight/true#M13642

Note that it turned out just recently that not only Linux but Windows is affected as well. Most people do not recognize this bug, because it only impacts those who do gaming (not Lenovo's primary target group) or heavy computation, like compiling stuff.

I know that it sounds quiet unbelievable, but it is actually true and there is nothing you can do about it but hope that Lenovo will fix this issue some day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you reinstalled Windows and it remains slow, it is not likely Windows. Our client Lenovo laptops tend to run very well.

1. Use Lenovo Software Updater to update ALL drivers including BIOS and Chipset.
2. Use Lenovo Diagnostics to check the hardware including the drive.
3. Look for older or legacy software and make sure all versions of all software are up to date.

My own X1 with NVMe SSD is a very fast machine. No lags anywhere.

Comment: I checked that everything is up to date with drivers, BIOS and chipset. I then ran Lenovo Diagnostics to check the hardware and there were no issues. I couldn't find any legacy software. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If all is up to date and you reinstalled Windows, then it should work. Back up, reinstall Windows only, make sure it is fast and then add software until something slows it down as before